# How to listen for smartcontract events and filter by receiver with Tron

Tags: blockchain, tron, tronweb

I'm trying to listen a specific event in USDT smartcontract on Tron blockchain. I want to update a database when a payment has been made to my address.

In order to do that, I use TronWeb. Here is my code :

```
const fullNode = 'https://api.shasta.trongrid.io';
const solidityNode = 'https://api.shasta.trongrid.io';
const eventServer = 'https://api.shasta.trongrid.io';
const tronweb = new Tronweb(fullNode,solidityNode,eventServer);
                    
let contract = await tronweb.contract().at('TG3XXyExBkPp9nzdajDZsozEu4BkaSJozs')
let watchTest = await contract.Transfer().watch({filters{"to":"TGdMonBPqH9THEhgNxMtHEcnxgbXxUuXeX"}},(err, res) => {
        if(res) {
                console.log(res)
        }
})
```

However, this code is printing every event emmited by the smart contract (not only the transfer to my address).

I'm looking for an equivalent of the following code with ethereum blokchain and ethers.js librairy :

```
let contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, provider);
let filter=contract.filters.Transfer(null, payment.PublicAddress);
provider.on(filter,async (log) => {})
```

What's the correct way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

The default contract info is obtained from event listeners.

```
const trc20ContractAddress = "Contractaddress"；
let contract = await tronWeb.contract().at(trc20ContractAddress);
await contract && contract.Transfer().watch((err, event) => {
   if(err)
      return console.error('Error with "Message" event:', err); 
      console.group('New event received');
      console.log('- Contract Address:', event.contract);
      console.log('- Event Name:', event.name);
      console.log('- Transaction:', event.transaction);
      console.log('- Block number:', event.block);
      console.log('- Result:', event.result, '\n');
      console.groupEnd();
});
```

this returns all the transactions from your contract address, and the data is filtered as per your requirements